# Historical CoronaVirus Papers

Tags: data-request, research, covid19, research-papers

I wonder where the historical Corona Virus research papers can be downloaded. Probably a bulk download of all papers from a couple of years or decades.

Comment: At [PubMed Central](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/) (PMC) you can do bulk download and **full-content papers** download, PDF or XML, all Open Licenced. At [pubmed](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/) bibliographic metadata only.

Answer (score 0):

[CoronaVirusPapers](https://the-eye.eu/public/Papers/CoronaVirusPapers/)

Historical Corona Virus Papers can be downloaded from [here](https://the-eye.eu/public/Papers/CoronaVirusPapers/). This directory contains 5,352 items. And it contains papers from 1968 to 2020. All papers are in PDF format.

```
wget -m -np -c -U "eye02" -w 2 -R "index.html*" "https://the-eye.eu/public/Papers/CoronaVirusPapers/"
```

Comment: this leads to an 404 error for me

Answer (score 0):

You can also search the Entrez Portal of NCBI. See [Entrez Programming Utilities Help](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK25501/).

A query to get publication metadata for papers from 1995 that have "Coronavirus" in their title: [https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esearch.fcgi?db=pubmed&term=coronavirus[title]%20AND%201995[pdat]](https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esearch.fcgi?db=pubmed&term=coronavirus%5Btitle%5D%20AND%201995%5Bpdat%5D)

This query does *not* give you the full text of these papers, only basic metadata about the results, and the first 20 ids of  papers found.

It would be your task then to follow up  on each paper ID (get more info from Entrez, fetch the PDF etc). I haven't done so here because you have already answered your own question, sufficiently.